# What will I be missing with xcode 3 and not getting xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, macos

If I only have xcode 3 what am I missing?  Should I hold off my project until I get xcode 4?

This would be for ios programming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You'll be missing the ability to ship software in the App Store.** Building for iOS 5 (which is required for App Store acceptance) requires Xcode 4.2. That's probably the single biggest thing. If you're just looking to try things out a bit, Xcode 3 will work. But if you're planning on shipping iOS software, you'll need to have Xcode 4.

Other than that, it's mostly just feature updates. Xcode 4 has a [number of features](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html) intended to speed up development. By sticking with Xcode 3, you'll be missing out on:

- Automatic Reference Counting
- Storyboards
- The ability to [drag directly from Interface Builder to your code](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#interface-builder)
- A much faster compiler
- Various bug fixes
- The ability to follow along with any of the recent tutorials referencing Xcode 4.

By sticking with Xcode 3, you get this:

- The ability to follow along with some of the older tutorials referencing Xcode 3.
- The ability to whine about "the good ol' days" when you finally switch to Xcode 4.

Comment: do you have any citation that XCode 4.2 + iOS 5 SDK is *required* for the app store?  I checked the [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) and found nothing mentioned there.  My answer would be that you **can submit** with XCode 3.2.6 and the iOS 4.X SDK via the Application Loader.  You just need to make sure your iOS 4.X (or 3.X) application continues to run and perform well in the iOS 5.X environment.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: Hm. I'll look, but I'm fairly certain that's the case. The most I've found so far is the June 2010 announcement (http://developer.apple.com/news/#top) saying ""All new applications and updates to existing applications must be built with iPhone SDK 4", which was the current SDK at the time.